# Por qué Data Factory no me deja hacer un copy data desde un Sql Server OnPremise a un Avro en cloud?

Tags: sql-server, azure

El mensaje de error que obtengo al intentar hacer un copydata con source en una tabla de Sql Server On Premise y Sink en un Avro apuntado hacia un blob storage es el siguiente;

ErrorCode=AvroFailedToSerializeData,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Serializae Avro Data failed. Message: Name 'COLUMNA_GENÉRICA' contains invalid characters..,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException,Message=Name 'COLUMNA_GENÉRICA' contains invalid characters.,Source=Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro,'

El problema surge que esas columnas en formato string no están pudiendo migrarse al avro.
Migrar desde un Sql Server On premise a Avro en cloud ya lo he hecho, me gusta usar Avro porque pensaba que era mas consistente en la integridad de los datos que quizás un csv que es mas enclenque.
Cual seria el problema?